# LinkedIn API Error 403 - Unable to Send Messages

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I am currently facing an issue while working with the LinkedIn API and trying to create an app that utilizes the endpoints related to products. When attempting to send messages via the API, I am encountering an Error 403.

[Screenshot of API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpHkx.png)

To provide more context, I am following the documentation provided at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/communications/messages?source=recommendations)

Issue Type: Applications (Apps on LinkedIn)

In Which App or Site?: Not App/Site Specific

On What Device?: Not Device Specific

Specifically, I am making requests to the API to send messages, but the server responds with a 403 error, which indicates a permission issue.

Here are some additional details that may help diagnose the problem:

I have checked my API credentials, and they appear to be correct.
I have reviewed the LinkedIn API documentation, and I believe I am using the endpoints correctly.
I have ensured that I have the necessary permissions for messaging in my LinkedIn app.
I am looking for guidance and assistance in resolving this issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem when working with the LinkedIn API or messaging endpoints? If you have any insights, suggestions, or solutions, please share them.

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not a screenshot.